# Django Jinja2 - AttributeError: 'FileSystemLoader' object has no attribute 'get_source' error

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using WEasyPrint and Jinja2 to generate a PDF out of a template, and have the following code:

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(self.app.templates_path))
template = env.get_template("order_scheduler/pdf_order_description.html") # ERROR
html_out = template.render()
```

The problem is that I am getting `AttributeError: 'FileSystemLoader' object has no attribute 'get_source'` on the second line of the code. Tried to surf the internet, but didn't find any sources on this.

I think, settings file content might be helpful. Find it below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'django_jinja',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supermarket_project.urls'
#ANONYMOUS_USER_ID=-1
TEMPLATES = [
     {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "match_extension": ".jinja",
        }
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","templates")],
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'  
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supermarket_project.wsgi.application'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
     )
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 148, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 146, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 184, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edgar\Desktop\djprj\djprj\vendor\views.py", line 383, in get_pdf
    template = env.get_template("pdf_order_description.html")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 812, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
    cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
AttributeError: 'FileSystemLoader' object has no attribute 'get_source'
```

The content of `pdf_order_description.html` is as simple as `<p>Stackoverflow</p>`

Any ideas how to fix the error ?

Comment: post the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're doing that stuff with `env` and FileSystemLoader at all.

Django already has support for Jinja2, and you've configured that in your settings. You should use the standard template loading functionality to get your Jinja template:

```
html_out = render_to_string('order_scheduler/pdf_order_description.jinja')
```

Note that you've configured the template loader to expect the extension "jinja" to load Jinja templates, so you should use that for your template.

Comment: Daniel, looks like you misprinted `.jinja`

Comment: And do I need the `request` parameter when calling `render_to_string` ?

Comment: And what about the `.jinja` extension ? Is it misprint as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which FileSystemLoader you are using. maybe the wrong import in your code. django_jinja wraps the loader.

https://github.com/niwinz/django-jinja/blob/master/django_jinja/loaders.py

vs. how a jinja Template looks like.

https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/loaders.py

Maybe you just need to specify the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`

https://github.com/niwinz/django-jinja/blob/b8073c2ae8f7c8350ab695c637b6a55e04998f69/testing/settings.py#L71